# I need a way to gather information about the address length and value length of each parachain

Tags: parachain, address, solidity, solang

Solang is a solidity compiler that compiles to the `wasm pallet`. In `Solang's CLI`, there are options to configure the target parachain address length and value length. What I want to add is a feature that enables the user to specify the target parachain on a high level `E.g. "pallet-contract with version v0.22.1"`, `"shiden parachain"` or `"substrate version X.Y.Z"`, then generate the correct address length and value length accordingly. My question is, where do I find the mapping between the parachain name and these parameters as there is no mention of the required information in the `parachains` docs.
Thanks!